# setTimeout function in javascript is being called but not setting timeout

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, settimeout

```
var r = 0;
var g = 0;
var b = 225;

function gradient() {
    b = b - 10;
}

while (b> 6){
    setTimeout(gradient(),1000);
}


ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle= 'rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')'
ctx.rect(0,0,1200,590,2*Math.PI)
ctx.stroke()
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

I know the `while` loop and function are working because the variable `b` is decreased and the color of the canvas image is changed. But there is no delay and it happens instantly. I have tried with the `setInterval` function as well but I can't get it to work.

Comment: usually, one passes a function to settimeout, not the result of calling a function  ... so, you'd do something like `setTimeout(gradient,1000);` - of course, even with this fix, it will not work like you expect, since b will be always over 10, and multiple setTimeouts will now be put in place and your browser will grind to a halt

Comment: also, since you use the current value of `b` in `ctx.fillStyle=`, changing the value of b after it's been used in that assignment won't change the fillStyle colour at all anyway - so, really, the code needs a complete rewrite to do what you want

Comment: @JaromandaX's comment is the correct answer (it should be added as an answer so it can be accepted).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 var r = 0;
 var g = 0;
 var b = 225;

 function gradient() {

   if(b > 6){
      console.log(b);
      b = b - 10;
      setTimeout(gradient,1000);
   }

 }

 gradient();

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle= 'rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')'
 ctx.rect(0,0,1200,590,2*Math.PI)
 ctx.stroke()
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.closePath();
```